# How to apply migration signature to an APK created by Flash Builder

Tags: android, migration, flash-builder, keystore, pfx

I developed an android application using Flash Builder.

Version 1.0 has been created with an old certificate (.PFX file).

That certificate is expired.

So I create new Version 1.1 with a new certificate.

But when I try to install the new version, the following message has been displayed.

> Application not installed: an existing package by the same name with a
>   conflicting signature is already installed.

**There is a simple solution**: Uninstall first version (1.0) and install the new version (1.1).

But I don't want to lose my application data which is created by 1.0 (old version).

Could anyone please suggest a **better solution**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, As of now there is no better solution for this situation.

Quoting the official documentation on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies),

> In general, the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all
>   of your applications with the same certificate, throughout the
>   expected lifespan of your applications. There are several reasons why
>   you should do so:
>
> - Application upgrade – As you release updates to your application, you
>     must continue to sign the updates with the same certificate or set of
>     certificates, if you want users to be able to upgrade seamlessly to
>     the new version. When the system is installing an update to an
>     application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with
>     those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly,
>     including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows
>     the update. If you sign the new version without using matching
>     certificates, you must also assign a different package name to the
>     application — in this case, the user installs the new version as a
>     completely new application.

So as per suggested by the documentation, You should create a key with maximum validity and use it for signing the application in future.

> Another important consideration in determining your signing strategy
>   is how to set the validity period of the key that you will use to sign
>   your applications.
>
> - If you plan to support upgrades for a single application, you should ensure that your key has a validity period that exceeds the
>     expected lifespan of that application. A validity period of 25 years
>     or more is recommended. When your key's validity period expires, users
>     will no longer be able to seamlessly upgrade to new versions of your
>     application.
> - If you will sign multiple distinct applications with the same key, you should ensure that your key's validity period exceeds the expected
>     lifespan of all versions of all of the applications, including
>     dependent applications that may be added to the suite in the future.
> - If you plan to publish your application(s) on Google Play, the key you use to sign the application(s) must have a validity period ending
>     after 22 October 2033. Google Play enforces this requirement to ensure
>     that users can seamlessly upgrade applications when new versions are
>     available.

So to conclude, You have to uninstall the old version and install the new one which is singed with the new certificate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can renew your old certificate with your Certificate Authority (CA) so that you will not face this conflict.

Comment: what do you mean by CA?

Comment: A CA is a certificate authority who would have issued your certificate in the first place.

Comment: Self signed certificates can be used to sign Android Applications. But renewing an expired certificate won't help with Android.